# Development board or Individual Microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, programming, hardware, development

I am an electrical engineering student and my planned career path is embedded systems. To get slightly ahead of my peers, but also for my own interests, I am learning embedded programming as well as purchasing some hardware to tinker with (possibly make my own smart devices or things of that nature).

Obviously, equipment such as an IDE, resistors, breadboards, wires, and other components are needed. And these things I have (I am using Keil MDK as my IDE). However, I would like to know the distinguishing factors between a development board, most likely a TI board like [this one](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/MSP-EXP430FR5994/6645208), and separate microcontrollers that can be purchased for under a dollar in most cases. Which option is more cost-friendly but also allows me to work on various projects? For example, one of the first projects I want to do is a motion sensor light for my kitchen pantry. Obviously, an entire development board is not necessary for this, but can I accomplish this with a simple $0.80 microcontroller?

Comment: Welcome!  Questions on Stack Exchange sites are required to be specific and specifically answerable.  Your question touches on many different topics and is not something which can be concisely and definitively answered within the mission of this site, and additionally gets into the prohibited territories of seeking opinions or purchase recommendations.  Likely you are at a position where personal research of the options is your most productive path forward.

Comment: I would recommend to always keep the application requirements in mind. You aren't building an embedded system, you are architecting a solution for a problem or need. Often this means making decisions that would not be the best from a pure design POV. Having a device to market faster is a benefit for your customers, hence, maximal reuse is often a valuable trait in a system designer. The more you bring for free, the more you can ask to be paid. Starting with development board is a no-brainer unless you have experienced resources to bring to bear or a very special need.

Comment: Get the Launchpad anyway. If you go with individual micros in the end, you'll still need to program them, and (assuming you stick with MSP430) you can use the Launchpad as a programmer (and debugger) using SBW (2-wire JTAG).

Comment: If you are only building a few and have a lot of physical space, go with a development board. The TI board you linked to is nice, I have a bunch of them. TI has really nice S/W tools. Many of the bare MCU chips are SMT, difficult for use until you have the tools and skill to solder them.

Comment: Definitely start with something user-friendly, on the hardware side at least. That can mean a development board from the chip manufacturer, it can mean something physically more compact marketed at the "maker community". Either way, the point is to not have to worry about the circuit while you're learning the chip / figuring out firmware.

Comment: @BrianDrummond So if I am interpreting your answer correctly, an MSP430 can be used to program and debug TI microcontrollers? That seems very useful and something I was not aware of before....

Comment: Not quite. The MSP430 Launchpads can be used to program and debug (most) TI MSP430 controllers. (All that support SWD : see the docs). I wouldn't want to assume it can program other TI microcontrollers.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Okay, thanks! I'll do some of my own research to find out some specifics of what is compatible. I appreciate the direction though!

Comment: I recommend starting with an arduino for 1 reason: support. Almost every little problem you will run into while getting things set up has been posted and solved by other hobbyists. The amount of technical support available varies dramatically with the platform you choose, and when you're getting started you will need a lot.

Comment: the fact you are asking this means you are not ready to roll your own pcb solution.  even an eval board you are going to need to glue/jumper stuff to it for this task.  work the basics the mcu is only part if it just like an engine by itself is not a car you need other systems around it to have them all work together to be something.

Comment: Yes, an Arduino has more support. If you only want to be a hobbyist, then get an Arduino. If you want to be an Engineer, get the MSP430. You will learn more, and it will look better on your resume. For support, there are people here that use MSP430, and the TI forums are helpful.

Comment: @Mattman944 I am definitely steering clear of Arduinos. In the school design team I am a part of, we are already working on manufacturing our custom-designed PCB (using Altium Designer), and I am doing alright with the theory and design aspect of it. I just want to start by getting my hands working a bit. Maybe solder some stuff, that kind of thing...

Answer (score 2):

You are in it for the experience, so there are no realy bad choices. Just do a lot of tinkering!

That said, do start with a ready-made PCB. I'd suggest an Arduino of some sort (my favourite is the Due, but you can do a lot with a Uno), others might steer you towards the evaluation boards for the various micro-controllers.

I'd suggest starting with the Arduino IDE. It is horrible, and coding standards for Arduino code seem to require very bad code, but the stuff WORKS. Once you have blinked a few LEDs, read a sensor, and drove some servo's, try to do the same without the Arduino IDE and libraries.

After that come back for more advice, or maybe join us in giving advice!

---

Responding to the comment:

When you have found your way around in the Arduino IDE / wiring (writing your own code, just re-building what others have done doesn't count), you could either (but only one step at the time):

- design your own PCB for a simple project (not too difficult with an AVR8), or
- ditch the IDE/wiring and program directly to the AVR8 hardware interface registers, using only the vendor-provided header file, or
- explore the use of C++ objects to bring more abstraction and re-useability to your projects (you could check my lib at github.com/wovo/hwlib).

Comment: I appreciate this answer for sure. I have already done some stuff with Arduinos and the Arduino IDE (several simple robots, like a color sorting robot). I am mainly asking for advice because within the next couple of years I will be working on very complicated projects and manufacturing my own boards. I want to get my feet wet in the "real world, doing things from scratch and problem-solving from there. It will no doubt be messy at first, but there is always a learning curve!

Answer (score 1):

You may know this already, but just in case anyone else needs it, I think it's important to note here that there is no difference whatsoever between the microcontroller on the dev board and the one you buy individually; an ATmega328P is an ATmega328P regardless of whether it's on a breadboard or on an arduino.

What the dev board does, then, is just provide all of the necessary hardware to run the micro, and usually also interface it to a computer, without needing to worry about hardware design (or, frequently, soldering); it gives you a ready-made solution in the hobbyist market, and in the commercial development market it gives you something to prototype with while working out the kinks in the design--and something for the programmers to program while the hardware people are still working on the final board.

*Some* dev boards that are mostly targeted at the hobbyist market, such as the Arduino, also have their own unique development environment in addition to code that's preloaded onto the microcontroller; the Arduino bootloader in this case, which allows the ATmega to communicate with the computer and be programmed without needing a separate programmer. The downside of this is that any code written with the Arduino IDE will require the target device to have the Arduino bootloader on it; you can't just go straight from the dev board to a custom board.

However, most dev boards don't work like that; you just write the code and program the chip identically to how you would on your own board. Dev boards may contain the programmer hardware separately as well, sometimes even letting you use the board as a dedicated programmer for microcontrollers other than the one on the dev board.

Answer (score 1):

A typical Dev board is like one of [these](https://he.aliexpress.com/item/32959871716.html):-

[image]

Festooned with 'cool' accessories you probably don't need, that just get in the way and have to be removed before you can use it for anything serious.

Trainer wheels are great for gaining confidence, but sooner or later you will have to learn to ride without them. You say that you have already done some stuff with Arduinos and the Arduino IDE, so you are ready to trade the toy bike in for a real one.

Get a bare MCU, an smd to DIP adapter if necessary, a breadboard and required components such as a crystal, capacitors and resistors etc. You should also have a variable power supply with current limit, a multimeter and an oscilloscope. Read the datasheets and app notes, and learn how to program the chip 'bare metal'.

Expect to have problems. *Solve them* and you will soon be way ahead of your peers.

Comment: That is the reassurance I need, thank you. Parts have been ordered and I am ready to go!